# Prime number subalgorithms

Tags: javascript, primes

Devise an algorithm to receive a positive number, n, and output all prime numbers that are smaller than n
and have a digit 7. For example, if n is 100, the program should output 7, 17, 37, 47, 67, 71, 73, 79, and 97.

Program freezes without giving output

```js
function P6() {
  var n = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a value"));

  for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    if (prime(i) && has7(i)) {
      alert(i);
    }
  }
}

function prime(s) {
  var flag = true;
  var d = 2;
  while (flag == true && d <= s / 2) {
    if (s % d == 0) {
      flag = false;
    }
    d = d++;
  }
  return flag;
}

function has7(v) {
  var has7 = false;
  var length = Math.log(v) + 1;
  for (var i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
    var last = v % 10;
    if (last == 7) {
      has7 = true;
    }
    v = v % 10
  }
  return has7;
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please expand it to a [mcve]

Comment: You need to return flag and has7 from the functions

Comment: Also you need var here: `for (var i = 1; i <= length; i++) {`

Comment: `&` should be `&&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
d = d++;
```

`d++` is a post-increment, it increments the variable but evaluates to the old value. So when you assign the result back to the variable, it sets it back to the original value. As a result, you have an infinite loop.

It should be either:

```
d = d + 1;
```

or just:

```
d++;
```

Another error is:

```
v = v % 10;
```

This is supposed to divide `v` by 10, but it's just setting `v` to its last digit. It should be:

```
v = Math.floor(v / 10);
```

In the code below, I've simplified all your loops. Rather than setting variables and continuing the loops, they return as soon as the loop can determine the answer. If the loop ends without returning, they return the opposite value.

```js
function P6() {
  var n = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a value"));

  for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    if (prime(i) && has7(i)) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
}

function prime(s) {
  for (var d = 2; d <= s / 2; d++) {
    if (s % d == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function has7(v) {
  while (v != 0) {
    var last = v % 10;
    if (last == 7) {
      return true;
    }
    v = Math.floor(v / 10);
  }
  return false;
}

P6();
```